# Passing codeigniter variable to wordpress theme file

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have installed wordpress in my root directory and codeigniter in a sub directory and everything works fine. I can call the CI controllers and all. However, I also want to use the same wordpress theme. eg: `get_header()`, `get_sidebar()` and `get_footer()`.

An example use would be to pass in my codeigniter page title so that wordpress does not show a `Page not found` title when accessing my codeigniter side. I have the following code:

A CI Controller:

```
public function index(){ 
    $data['ci_title'] = 'some title'; 
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
}
```

The CI view (header.php):

`<?php get_header(); ?>`;

Wordpress theme file (header.php):

```
<title>
    <?php
        if($ci_title) echo $ci_title else wp_title('');
    ?>
</title>
```

Now the problem is my `$ci_title` isn't being read in the wordpress theme file. I even tried putting `globlal $ci_title` in the `get_header()` function, but there it again calls some `load_template()` function.

Is there an easy way to pass CI variables to wordpress theme files?

Comment: Can I ask, what's your purpose of doing this?

Comment: @KemalFadillah I am making a site where the main part is a CMS, but it also has some other data that needs to be retrieved and displayed to the visitor with search/sort functions. CI will be used to access that data, and I don't want to write a custom blog/CMS in CI.

Comment: I don't know an easy way but you can just make a header file based on a rendered pages source code.  But then you have to update that file everytime you update the header which is a pain, but if you don't have to do that ever then thats not a problem.

Comment: Does header.php (CodeIgniter view) contain `<?php get_header(); ?>;` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes. The CI view (header.php) countains the code to call the WP header i.e. `<?php get_header(); ?>` but the variable `$ci_title` is not being accessed in the WP header due to scope. Inside the `get_header()` function, it again calls another function and so on. Maybe I should just create a `ci_header.php` file with the same contents as the WP except for the various variables I need, and call it instead from my controller. But that way, I would need to create two files with almost the same content.

Comment: What happens if you echo the variable before the `get_header();` call ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera The variable is echoed as expected. But within the `get_header()` it disappears. I could pass it as a parameter from my view file to the `get_header()` function and change the WP `get_header()` function to accept another parameter, but then, I will have to again pass it inside that function and to another and another.

Comment: I think you have to do this, read this http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/110/

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to go and modify the core files. What you have to do is just simply add the following lines of code in your header.php

```
$CI = &get_instance(); 
echo $CI->load->get_var('ci_title');
```

you will get all the variables passed in loader object of CI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after going through alot and finally reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#98811 , found out I needed to declare my `$ci_title` as `global` before calling `get_header()`. Now my code looks like the following:

CI View file (header.php):

```
global $ci_title;
get_header();
```

WP function `wp_title()` in `general-template.php`

```
function wp_title($sep = '&raquo;', $display = true, $seplocation = '', $ci_title = '') {
global $wpdb, $wp_locale, $ci_title;
//existing code.. and at the end
if($ci_title != ''){
$title = $ci_title;
```

Don't know if it's the right way to do it since I am just a beginner in PHP, but right now it serves my purpose. Would be nice if there was a better way though, something which makes me avoid modifying the wordpress functions.